# Publishing Speed | QUEUE_CONSUMERS Table

Tags: 2013, publishing, 2013-sp1

Experts,

We have recently migrated to 2013 Sp1. And doing mass publishing.
The publishing speed is about 1000 items per hour and it seems not enough (I know it depends on items, templating, custom resolver and deployer). 
I was just wondering if we can make it faster.

For this I have done some investigation , starting form “QUEUE_CONSUMERS” table as below
[image]

We are using “PUB-1” server for publishing. But it is also ‘IS_ONLINE’ for “CMS-1” (Queue_ID = 1)
Could it be a factor for low publishing performance?

Also, we neither use CMS-1 nor PUB-1 for Deployer. but both are Online for it (Queue_ID = 2).
Is it also related?

Yes, I know, its allowed to touch the DB and it will make it unsupported from SDL. I am just asking if it could be a issue? Or any other thing you want to recommend to check.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is factor to increase your performance :).
Queue_Consumer table contains instances of the Tridion services, which can handle some Queue...Tridion supports enabling more than one Publisher, Deployer or Batch service (queue_id = 5 in your table)...So, this services support Scale-out.

After new queue_message appears in Queue_messages table message is sent (if I am not mistaken by UDP) to all consumers, which can handle this queue...And after that in concurrent mode (if consumer is not single) execution of some operation starts.

About online status: Check both hosts and whether Publisher is run on them. When services stop correctly IS_Online becomes 0 (or even record can be deleted from database). 
If I am not mistaken - Publisher handles both publish and deploy queues.

PS: for your initial problem I can advice you to calculate manually how many time you need to render one item... Problems can be in different places.

Answer (score 1):

Options

- if you have decent multi-core machine, you can experiment with following option(SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration) and come to some optimized numbers

[image]

- if you have heave load on CMS machine, configure a different publisher.
- Make sure your c# tbbs are compiled in release mode (minor)

Comment: And yes...this also can help you...
It is Scale-In which is supported by Tridion services.
This value means, how many concurrent threads in your service can try to resolve queue message (btw - it is not recommended to set this value more than number of Cores on your PC...in this case, probably you will not get any gain)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the "deployer" queue is not really the deployer; the deployer is part of the Content Delivery subsystem and usually does not run on your Publisher or WebGUI box. The deployer does NOT query the CM queues from the CM database. The same applies to "number of threads for deployment" in the Tridion Content Manager configuration (the deployer is not part of the Content Management environment but the Content Delivery environment so it makes no sense to configure it on the Content Management environment).

My best guess is that this is actually for the transport service (a.k.a sending for deployment) but perhaps someone with a more in-depth knowledge of the CM queues can confirm or correct this?